# integral solutions to a prime number?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

> Find the number of non-negative integer solutions to:
>   $$(x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n)(y_1+y_2+\cdots + y_p)=P$$
>   where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $P$ is a prime number.

I know the answer is $2n\binom{p+n-1}{p}$ but I don't understand why?

Comment: Are $p$ and $P$ supposed to be the same number?

Comment: The factors in the left are either $\;1,\,p\;$ or the other way around.

Comment: the small p does not have to be prime, but the large P is prime. That is an assumption though.

Comment: I understand the combination, that is simply a multiset combination, but why on earth do we take that combination and times it by 2 times the amount of elements in first factor.

Comment: Based on the answer you have, I think the second factor should be $(y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_n)$.

Comment: Thank you user84413. you are correct. the incorrect labeling was done. So, thats say that the first factor goes to x_4 and the second factor goes to y_5. it would be 20 times the combination, since (5)(4) are the factors together?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $ P $ being prime means that its factors are $ 1 $ and $ P $, so the integer solutions to that equation satisfy either
$$ x_1 + \dots + x_n = 1 \text{ and } y_1 + \dots + y_p = P$$
or
$$ x_1 + \dots + x_n = P \text{ and } y_1 + \dots + y_p = 1 $$

So your answer should be the sum of the numbers of solutions to these two sets of equations